# Using sockets to send a UDP packet to see online state

Tags: php, minecraft

I've created a function that lets me see if a minecraft bedrock (MCPE) server is online, these servers run on the UDP protocol as far as i'm aware.

UDP is a connectionless protocol, meaning it doesn't let you know that it's online or offline until you actually read or write something.

I've created a function that should be doing this, though it always seems to be returning my udp variable true, saying that it's online.

Does anyone know what could be the cause of this?

```
/**
 * @return bool
 */
public function checkUDP(): bool
{
    $udp = false;

    if ($result = resolveSRV($this->address, $this->port, 'udp')) {
        $this->address = $result['address'];
        $this->port    = $result['port'];
    }

    $udpConnection = @fsockopen('udp://' . $this->address, $this->port, $errCode, $errMsg, 2);

    if ($udpConnection !== false) {
        $OFFLINE_MESSAGE_DATA_ID = pack('c*', 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00, 0xFE, 0xFE, 0xFE, 0xFE, 0xFD, 0xFD, 0xFD, 0xFD, 0x12, 0x34, 0x56, 0x78);

        $command = pack('cQ', 0x01, time()); // DefaultMessageIDTypes::ID_UNCONNECTED_PING + 64bit current time
        $command .= $OFFLINE_MESSAGE_DATA_ID;
        $command .= pack('Q', 2); // 64bit guid
        $length = strlen($command);

        // Set a longer timeout
        stream_set_timeout($udpConnection, 2);

        if ($length === fwrite($udpConnection, $command, $length)) {
            $udp = true;
        }

        fclose($udpConnection);
    }

    return $udp;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be confused by the document, in fact write error only occurs when the socket is closed, UDP does not care if the data is sent successfully. You can determine that the endpoint is working properly when it returns the desired response. So you should use `fread` and check its return value.

```
if ($length === fwrite($udpConnection, $command, $length)) {
    $result = fread($udpConnection, 128);
    if(!empty($result) && $result == <desired response>)
        $udp = true;
}
```